# Passing arguments to a shell script via stdin multiple times

Tags: bash, stdin

I have a script `StartProcess.sh` that accepts two options in `stdin` - `3` and a filename `test.xml`.

If I run the below script, it executes correctly, and waits again for the input.
I want someway to pass `3` and `test.xml` `n` times to `StartProcess.sh`. How do I achieve this.

```
./StartProcess.sh << STDIN -o other --options 
3
test.xml
STDIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop to pass the arguments as many times in a loop and run a script over a pipe-line. That way, the script is just launched once and the arguments gets sent over stdin any number of times of your choice

```
count=3
for (( iter = 0; iter < 3; iter++ )); do
    echo "3" "test.xml"
done | StartProcess.sh
```

But I'm not fully sure if you wanted to pass the literal string `test.xml` as an argument or the content of the file.